# Angularjs $scope and this functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, this

I am working on a small application in angularjs :-

I am working on deleting a contact. Everything works fine but the this.openModal() throws an error as undefined even though it is defined in the same JS.

Have some confusions on how to use this and $scope together.
Can anyone help ?

```
$scope.deleteContact = function ()
{
    var delNo = $scope.contactNumber;
    var delName = $scope.contactName;

    var person = {};
    person['phone'] = delNo;

    ...
    ...
    $timeout(function(){
        delete $scope.contacts[person['phone']];
        });

    $scope.activeChats={};
    $scope.showContactName = false;
    this.openModal();

    console.log("Delete success");

}
```

**EDIT:**

this.openModal is a function I have defined as follows

```
this.openModal = function (input) {
    this.modalOpen = !this.modalOpen;
    // RESET
    this.showNewMessage = false;
    this.showEditGroup = false;
    this.showAddContact = false;
    this.showPersonSettings = false;
    this.showUserProfile = false;

    if (input == "newmessage"){
        this.showNewMessage = true;
    } else if (input == "showEditGroup"){
        this.showEditGroup = true;
    } else if (input == "newcontact"){
        this.showAddContact = true;
    } else if (input == "userprofile"){
        this.showUserProfile = true;
    } else if (input == "usersettings"){
        this.showPersonSettings = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `openModal()` defined exactly? What do you *think* `this` refers to? Also: this doesn't sound like the angular way to approach this task.

Comment: Are you going to use the Angular Bootstrap modal window? Where is `this.openModal()` defined?

Comment: If you could confirm whether you are using the Bootstrap UI, or Foundation Directives, I can give you further assistance with the Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're doing but I suppose you're having some context issues executing async functions. Try assigning `$scope` to a local variable closing it over in your function block and use the variable in asnyc functions' blocks.

```
$scope.deleteContact = function ()
{
    var person = {
        phone: $scope.contactNumber
    };

    ...

    // save scope reference to local variable
    var scope = $scope;

    $timeout(function(){
        // use saved scope
        delete scope.contacts[person['phone']];
    });

    $scope.activeChats={};
    $scope.showContactName = false;
    this.openModal();

    console.log("Delete success");
}
```

There's also another way that somewhat does something similar in but inside angular's code. And that's `angular.bind`. Use it in your `$timeout`. The similarity is that you provide the function's context in the time of execution, so `this` is what you provide. In the following case I'm providing `$scope` to be the execution context of the async function this referring to it using `this`:

```
$timeout(angular.bind($scope, function(){
    // context (this) is actually $scope
    delete this.contacts[person['phone']];
}));
```

Comment: What actually is happening here is that :- I am working on a popup window while deleting the contact, on success I want the popup to close which I am doing using the openModal function which resets every popup window.

Answer (score 1):

You use either `$scope` or `this` in two scenarios. The first scenario where you use the binding:

```
ng-controller="MyCtrl"
```

Or in the route:

```
when('/color', { controller : 'MyCtrl' });
```

Here, angular js expects you include the `$scope` service in your controllers and attach bindable properties to that:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', myCtrl]);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Hello";
}
```

In the second scenario, you define a `controllerAs` and this is where angular will expect to see the bindable properties on the controller object, controller as a class. I prefer this method because it looks cleaner.

```
ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm"
```

Or in the route:

```
when('/color', { controller : 'MyCtrl', controllerAs: 'vm' });
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyCtrl', [myCtrl]);

function myCtrl() {
    this.title = "Hello";

    // or to make sure that you don't get JS contexts mixed up
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = "Hello";

    vm.openModal = function () {
        this;// this refers to the current function scope

        vm.title = "Modal Opened"; // this refers to the controller scope
        // scope as in the JS function context.
    }
}
```

In the second scenario, the binded page will look like this:

```
<h3>{{vm.title}}</h3>
```

Where you use the 'controllerAs' string as the object you use to access the properties.

So to answer the question: **Have some confusions on how to use this and $scope together**

You generally would use one or the other. In the second scenario you would only inject the `$scope` if you needed to `$watch` a property, or use some other special scope function.

Comment: hey I have a problem calling sub function inside function code look like this         function foo(){    this.sam = function(){  alert('helllo')  }      }      in my controller I try calling it using this.foz = foo.sam;  but it doesnt work